# Establish relationship between two text fields

Tags: views

I am stuck in a strange issue. I have two content types `twilio`  and call `recordings`. Both content types have `caller phone number` in common

1. Recording

   [image: screenshot]
2. Twilio

   [image: screenshot]

Now I would like to generate a report using `views` which can select field between two content types based on `phone number`.

In non Drupal terms I want **inner join** based on two **text fields.**

How can I achieve this?

Comment: based on a quick look at the images you attached, you don't have common field in both content-type, make 1 field first, then add an existing field to the second content-type, so you can have common fields!

Comment: The fields are not common, but the purpose is common. I want to implement this without altering any structure

Comment: I can smell of a custom module for that, I don't see any way out.

Answer (score 1):

Both content types have to share a field, in the same way a both the database tables used in a `INNER JOIN` have to share a common field for the join to work.

In Drupal, this is easy as you can reuse fields between your content types and in this wway joining the content types will be super simple with Views.

**Current setup:**

> Recording: field_called_phone, field_caller_phone
>
> Twilio: field_phone_number

**Suggested setup:**

> Recording: field_called_phone, ***field_phone_number***
>
> Twilio: ***field_phone_number***